# Why does this code work for chrome but not for firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got here some javascript code, that implements a signature pad. It works fine on google chrome but it doesn't work on firefox. Here is the code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Signature Pad</title>
     <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      //fires when document is loaded and DOM is ready.
      $(document).ready(function() {

  var context, canvas, drawLine, mouseIsPressed, x, y, prevX, prevY, borderWidth;
         canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); //retrieve canvas from dom by id that we have assigned
         context = canvas.getContext('2d'); //retrieve context
         borderWidth = 5; //let border width will be 5 pixel
         canvas.style.border = borderWidth + " px solid #00F000"; // 5 pixel width solid green border
         drawLine = function(x1, y1, x2, y2)
         {
            context.beginPath(); //create a path
            context.moveTo(x1 - borderWidth, y1 - borderWidth); //move to
            context.lineTo(x2 - borderWidth, y2 - borderWidth); //draw a line
            context.stroke(); // filled with "ink"
            context.closePath(); //close path
         };
         canvas.onmousedown = function(evt)
         {
            mouseIsPressed = true; //save that mouse is pressed
            drawLine(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, evt.offsetX + 1, evt.offsetY + + 1) //draw short line that looks like a dot
         };
         canvas.onmouseup = function(evt)
         {
            mouseIsPressed = false; //save that mouse is released
         };
         canvas.onmousemove = function(evt)
         {
            x = evt.offsetX; 
            y = evt.offsetY; //get current X and Y
            if(mouseIsPressed)
            {
               drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);  //draw a line on canvas from previous to current point.
            }
            prevX = x; prevY = y; //save previous x and y in both case, weather mouse is pressed or not
         };
      });



      </script>
   <head>
   <body>
      <canvas width="300" height="200" id="canvas"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

Firefox does support HTML5 Canvas as far as i know. And I do have Version 6. I also checked if javascript was disabled, but that wasn't the problem. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the console show you? Any reported errors?

Comment: Are you sure Firefox supports HTML5? I've been using Chrome for a while now so I don't know where FF is on that-- but I would double check that FF (and your installed version in particular) supports Canvas. EDIT - ok, a little Googling shows that it does, but make sure your version does.

Comment: @transistor1: Why not check first? If Google is too hard, there is still http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Comment: @Wladimir Palant - ouch. As you can see, I _did_ check before you made your _friendly_ post; but OP _still_ needs to check if his/her version supports Canvas, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things you need to change:
1. borderWidth + " px solid #00F000"; The border won't show in Firefox. Remove the empty before px.
2. change offsetX to clientX
3. change offsetY to clientY

The final code:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>Signature Pad</title> 
     <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      //fires when document is loaded and DOM is ready. 
      $(document).ready(function() { 

  var context, canvas, drawLine, mouseIsPressed, x, y, prevX, prevY, borderWidth; 
         canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); //retrieve canvas from dom by id that we have assigned 
         context = canvas.getContext('2d'); //retrieve context 
         borderWidth = 5; //let border width will be 5 pixel 
         canvas.style.border = borderWidth + "px solid #00F000"; // 5 pixel width solid green border 

         drawLine = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) 
         { 
            context.beginPath(); //create a path 
            context.moveTo(x1 - borderWidth, y1 - borderWidth); //move to 
            context.lineTo(x2 - borderWidth, y2 - borderWidth); //draw a line 
            context.stroke(); // filled with "ink" 
            context.closePath(); //close path 
         }; 
         canvas.onmousedown = function(evt) 
         { 
            mouseIsPressed = true; //save that mouse is pressed 
            drawLine(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, evt.clientX + 1, evt.clientY + + 1) //draw short line that looks like a dot 
         }; 
         canvas.onmouseup = function(evt) 
         { 
            mouseIsPressed = false; //save that mouse is released 
         }; 
         canvas.onmousemove = function(evt) 
         { 
            x = evt.clientX;  
            y = evt.clientY; //get current X and Y 
            if(mouseIsPressed) 
            { 
               drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);  //draw a line on canvas from previous to current point. 
            } 
            prevX = x; prevY = y; //save previous x and y in both case, weather mouse is pressed or not 
         }; 
      }); 

      </script> 
   <head> 
   <body> 
      <canvas width="300" height="200" id="canvas" >Not support</canvas> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's event structures is a bit different from chromes. Try changing offsetX to clientX

Comment: Now it works. But the borders of the canvas are not set. Any Idea how to solve that?

Comment: @Luke -see my post at line "canvas.style.border=" and comment - it describes why border are not set/

Answer (score 1):

Use next code for SCRIPT block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //fires when document is loaded and DOM is ready.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var context, canvas, drawLine, mouseIsPressed, x, y, prevX, prevY, borderWidth;
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'); //retrieve context
    borderWidth = 5;
    canvas.style.border = borderWidth + "px solid #00F000"; // **here is no space before "px" for properly border drawing of canvas**
    drawLine = function(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    {
      context.beginPath(); //create a path
      context.moveTo(x1 - borderWidth, y1 - borderWidth); //move to
      context.lineTo(x2 - borderWidth, y2 - borderWidth); //draw a line
      context.stroke(); // filled with "ink"
      context.closePath(); //close path
    };
    canvas.onmousedown = function(evt)
    {
      mouseIsPressed = true; //save that mouse is pressed
      drawLine(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, evt.clientX + 1, evt.clientY + 1);
      prevX=evt.clientX; prevY=evt.clientY; // **You must initialize prevX and prevY firstly and use clientX, clientY** see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent][1]
    };
    canvas.onmouseup = function(evt)
    {
      mouseIsPressed = false; //save that mouse is released
    };
    canvas.onmousemove = function(evt)
    {
      x = evt.clientX; 
      y = evt.clientY;
      if(mouseIsPressed)
      {
        drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);
      }
      prevX = x; prevY = y;
    };
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php, shows that

drawLine(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, evt.offsetX + 1, evt.offsetY + + 1)

is missing a semi-colon. Does that solve it?

Comment: OK, apologies. However in my experience it is always worth running js through lint when something seems amiss, particularly if works differently on different browsers. I know the issue is in FF and not Chrome, but Chrome's js console does often give useful warnings when result in actual errors in other browsers. Does Chrome's js console tell you anything?